# Implement HTTP call retries with Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I'm calling rest services from azure functions I want implement Retry something like this. How we can do this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly

```
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content));
                T output = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return output;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options :

1. Use durable functions, it has Retries in built. e.g.

   ```
   var a1 = await ctx.CallActivityWithRetryAsync<string>("Function", 
   new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),10)
   {
       Handle = ex => ex.InnerException.Message == "Monitoring failed."
   }, 
   inputData);
   ```

More details on Azure Durable Functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp

2. OR Have a message broker architecture having queue for sending data & process data in azure from service bus queue triggered function. service bus queue have in built retry

Comment: @Pranave, Where I can but the external URL or if i have two different server-less function which developed as separate solution. how we  are going each other